# Imported texture is just black?

Tags: image

[image]
Not sure what's going on here. My node setup is correct and the .TIF file i'm using doesn't have any problems (in the Image editor panel my image is displayed. It is UV unwrapped properly.
This is the image I'm trying to use:
[image]

*(It's a baked dynamic paint)*

I was thinking maybe it's because it's a transparent image, but I tried using another transparent .TIF I got online, and it seemed to work just fine:
[image]
*(The smily face image is just B&W and Transparent, same as the other picture that won't work)*

[Here's a link to the proper file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EMjBheEZSZ0RTbEk)

Comment: Since as this exact node setup works with another image, but not yours, I'm thinking the files location might be wrong

Comment: @Lukaash I've checked that, it's not it

Comment: Silvenous Have you tried different file types or can you only use a .TIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting an all-black image with an alpha channel to a diffuse shader, and Blender won't know what to do with the transparent areas.

It will paint black in the black areas, but in the transparent areas there is no color information, so it will... paint black.

Also as far as I know TIFF images have the ability to save color information even for fully transparent areas, whereas in your case they are black, with full transparency (as can even be seen directly in the google drive link preview you provide). So if Cycles where to use the color information for those transparent pixels it would yeild... black again.

Either

1. Use the alpha channel to mix two colors.
2. Use the alpha channel to mix two different shaders.
3. Change your picture to a black&white image instead of all black with alpha
4. Change your picture to have white pixels in the transparent areas

[image: All black transparent TIFF]

Comment: What .GIF capture program do you use?

Comment: [ScreenToGIf](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif)

Comment: Also, what theme is that? That isn't a preset, is it?

Comment: Its the Flatty Light preset, might have changed a few minor things around eventually, not really sure anymore.